# URL Rewriting in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a basic requirement in my app:

I have already running my site that is built on asp.net platform. Now I am converting my asp.net application into asp.net mvc but the problem arises in Url. I want my asp.net Services.aspx page redirect to Services controller

I had created simple asp.net mvc project and a controller given below:

```
public class ServicesController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Please help me how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain little bit more on this.

Comment: For example: I have a asp.net site with a page Services.aspx and it is running as www.xyz.com/Services.aspx. Now I created a new asp.net mvc site to provide Service page to user (www.xyz.com/Services). Now I want that whatever request will go to Services.aspx will be redirected to ServicesController Index action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can accomplish this in a variety of ways. Since you are using ASP.NET MVC, I would suggest you just change the routes.

The first step is to edit the web.config file and add the appropriate handler. This will point all files with .aspx to the [TransferRequestHandler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4/). If you remove the wildcard `*`, you can specify the exact file name you want handled (this probably isn't necessary for your needs). You should add this in between the `<system.webServer><handlers>` tags:

```
<add name="AspxFileHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Then you will want to edit the route configuration which you can find under App_Start -> RouteConfig.cs. If there are existing webform files on the server then you will want to add:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Now to add the Custom Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Services",
     url: "Services.aspx",
     defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
);
```

To summarize, your web.config should look something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
          <add name="AspxFileHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
          <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
          <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
      </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And your RouteConfig like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Services",
          url: "Services.aspx",
          defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```